# XQuery to get a multi-valued field in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am getting this error since we made a field multi-valued (a list of multiple of the same elements):

`argX is not of type xs:anyAtomicType?`

This is the query that we are using to get values from MarkLogic:

```
declare variable $uris as xs:string  external;
for $uri in tokenize($uris,';')
    let $doc := fn:doc($uri)
    return xdmp:gzip(
        xdmp:unquote(fn:concat(
            "<item>",
            "<uri>",
            $uri,
            "</uri>",
            "<date-loaded>",
            $doc/date-loaded,
            "</date-loaded>",
            "<collections>",
                string-join(xdmp:document-get-collections($uri), ";"),
            "</collections>",
            "</item>"
        ))
    )
```

Now the field `<date-loaded>` can have multiple values like this:

```
<date-loaded>2020-01-01</date-loaded>
<date-loaded>2020-01-02</date-loaded>
<date-loaded>2020-01-03</date-loaded>
```

Here the order is important. How should I change this query in a correct one that retrieves all the values of `date-loaded` and put them each in a separate XML element?

Comment: what do your docs look like? How can `$doc/date-loaded` select multiple items? Is that XPath selecting a sequence of `text()` nodes for those dates i.e. first item is "2020-01-01" or is it selecting a sequence of elements `<date-loaded>2020-01-01</date-loaded>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things would be easier and more simple if you weren't creating a string to parse as XML, but leveraged the XQuery language to do it for you:

```
for $uri in tokenize($uris,';')
let $doc := fn:doc($uri)
return 
  xdmp:gzip(<item>
              <uri>{$uri}</uri>
              {$doc/date-loaded} 
              <collections>{string-join(xdmp:document-get-collections($uri), ";") }</collections>
            </item>)
```

And if you wanted those `date-loaded` elements listed in a particular order instead of document-order from the source, you could sort them in a FLOWR:

```
{ 
  for $date in $doc/date-loaded
  order by $date
  return $date
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, your query is the solution! This is an example output record: `<item>
<uri>XYZ</uri>
<date-loaded>2020-10-16</date-loaded>
<date-loaded>2020-10-27</date-loaded>
<collections>...</collections>
</item>`